# Transfer int using pipe between N number of process

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I want to transfer data between multiple child process using pipe() like that :
[image: multiple child process that use pipe to communicate]

And that need to work for any number of child process. I want to see child process print the read pipe value and increment this value by one and transfers this values to the next process.

But for now, I have 3 problems :

- My child function was call multiple time with the same parameter
- Because of that, the file descriptor change and I don't want that.
- Every process except the first one get `Bad file descriptor` with errno

Everything seams to work for the first one because it receives the value from father and have no error when write to the writePipe.

When I run my program, this is my console output

```
id:0 pipeRead:5 PipeWrite:8
id:0 res:4 value:500
id:1 pipeRead:9 PipeWrite:12
id:2 pipeRead:13 PipeWrite:16
id:1 pipeRead:3 PipeWrite:6
id:2 pipeRead:7 PipeWrite:10
id:1 res:-1 value:0
id:2 pipeRead:3 PipeWrite:6
id:2 res:-1 value:0
Read Error: Bad file descriptor
Read Error: Bad file descriptor
```

So, here my code attempt

```c
int execChild(int appID,  int pipeRead[2], int pipeWrite[2]){
    //Before start process, I close read/write that not used here
    //Close write of read pipe
    close(pipeRead[1]);
    //Close read of write pipe
    close(pipeWrite[0]);

    printf("id:%d pipeRead:%d PipeWrite:%d\n",appID,pipeRead[0],pipeWrite[1]);

    int buff=0;
    long int res;
    res = read(pipeRead[0],&buff,sizeof(int));
    if (res==-1) perror("Read Error");
    //Close read pipe after used
    close(pipeRead[0]);

    printf("id:%d res:%ld value:%d\n",appID,res,buff);
    //Increment value
    buff += 1;

    res = write(pipeWrite[1],&buff,sizeof(int));
    if(res==-1)perror("Write Error");
    //Close write pipe after used
    close(pipeWrite[1]);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int nbFis = 3;

    //Init array of pipeArray with malloc
    int* pipeArr[nbFis];
    for (int i = 0; i < nbFis; i++)
        pipeArr[i] = (int*)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    
    for (int i = 0; i < nbFis; i++) // Generate n child
    {
        //Here we open every inter child pipe
        //If the process is 0 we need to open the last pipe of the array
        //Else we open the last pipe
        if(i==0){
            pipe(pipeArr[nbFis-1]);//Open Read Pipe
            //To test I inject an int value here to child 0
            int value = 500;
            write(pipeArr[nbFis-1][1],&value,sizeof(int));//Write value in the pipe
        }else{
            pipe(pipeArr[i-1]);//Open Read Pipe
        }
        pipe(pipeArr[i]);//Open Write Pipe
        
        if (fork() == 0) {
            //If it's the first child we send the last pipe in the array as read pipe and current pipe as write pipe
            //Else we send the previous pipe in the list as read pipe and current pipe as write pipe
            if(i==0){
                execChild(i,pipeArr[nbFis-1],pipeArr[i]);
            }else{
                execChild(i,pipeArr[i-1],pipeArr[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    //Wait for the end of process and free memory
    for (int i = 0; i < nbFis; i++) {
        free(pipeArr[i]);
        wait(NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For `nbFis` children you want `nbFis` pipes, but you create two pipes on each iteration of the loop, so you get twice that many.  Since you need to give two pipes to each child, it would be relatively natural to create one before entering the loop, and then create one more on each iteration of the loop except the last.

Comment: Yes, I want only one pipe by process, but I need to send 2 pipes to each child : read that come from the previous one in list and write that use in the next child. 
So, how I can open the pipe correctly without this duplication?

Comment: Again, you could create one pipe before entering the loop, and one more on each iteration except the last.  Alternatively, you could create all the pipes first, and then, separately, create all the children.

Comment: You totally right, that works!

My value was sending between the child. But I continue to have multiple call of my execChild function.